# Is it possible in a Retrofit Post request to accept other data than the one sent?

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

In Java Android I use Retrofit.  I need to post a request to send user data - first name, last name, age, phone number, password.  And in response, his id and token should come.How to make such a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class to represent the response.

```java
class RegisterResponse {
    private long id;
    private String token;
    public AuthResponse(long id, String token) {
        this.id = id;
        this.token = token;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

Then, your Retrofit method could look like this:

```java
@Post("/somepath")
RegisterResponse register(@Query("firstname") String firstName, @Query("lastname") String lastName /* other parameters... */);
```

You could also make another class to represent the body of the request rather than writing out each parameter separately.